# Custom spray rejection handler not working properly in tests

Tags: scala, akka, spray, specs2

I am building some JSON HTTP services using `spray` and I am having some problems testing a `RejectionHandler`. If I start the application running the command `sbt run` and make the request, the `RejectionHandler` process the `MalformedRequestContentRejection` as expected but I am getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when running the tests even with the route sealed. In the other hand, the `MethodRejection` works fine. The JSON validation is done using `require`

The next example is based in the `spray-template` [repository](https://github.com/spray/spray-template) branch `on_spray-can_1.3_scala-2.11` with a POST endpoint and the new tests. I've made a fork with the entire example [here](https://github.com/Quaiks/spray-template)

Notice the use of a `case clase` for deserialize JSONs, the use of the `require` method for validation and the declaration of an implicit `RejectionHandler`.

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.Actor
import spray.routing._
import spray.http._
import StatusCodes._
import MediaTypes._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

class MyServiceActor extends Actor with MyService {
  def actorRefFactory = context
  def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}

case class SomeReq(field: String) {
  require(!field.isEmpty, "field can not be empty")
}
object SomeReq {
  import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
  implicit val newUserReqFormat = jsonFormat1(SomeReq.apply)
}

trait MyService extends HttpService {
  implicit val myRejectionHandler = RejectionHandler {
    case MethodRejection(supported) :: _ => complete(MethodNotAllowed, supported.value)
    case MalformedRequestContentRejection(message, cause) :: _ => complete(BadRequest, "requirement failed: field can not be empty")
  }
  val myRoute =
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      post {
        entity(as[SomeReq]) { req =>
          {
            complete(Created, req)
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This is are the test implemented using `spray-testkit`. The last one expects a `BadRequest` but the test fails with an `IllegarArgumentException`.

```
package com.example

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest
import spray.http._
import StatusCodes._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

class MyServiceSpec extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest with MyService {
  def actorRefFactory = system

  "MyService" should {
    "leave GET requests to other paths unhandled" in {
      Get("/kermit") ~> myRoute ~> check {
        handled must beFalse
      }
    }
    "return a MethodNotAllowed error for PUT requests to the root path" in {
      Put() ~> sealRoute(myRoute) ~> check {
        status should be(MethodNotAllowed)
        responseAs[String] === "POST"
      }
    }
    "return Created for POST requests to the root path" in {
      Post("/", new SomeReq("text")) ~> myRoute ~> check {
        status should be(Created)
        responseAs[SomeReq] === new SomeReq("text")
      }
    }
    /* Failed test. Throws IllegalArgumentException */
    "return BadRequest for POST requests to the root path without field" in {
      Post("/", new SomeReq("")) ~> sealRoute(myRoute) ~> check {
        status should be(BadRequest)
        responseAs[String] === "requirement failed: field can not be empty"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SomeReq` class is being eagerly instantiated in the `Post("/", new SomeReq(""))` request builder and the `require` method is invoked as soon as the `class` is instantiated.

To get around this try using the following instead:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
Post("/", JsObject("field" → JsString(""))) ~> sealRoute(myRoute) ~> check {
  status should be(BadRequest)
  responseAs[String] === "requirement failed: field can not be empty"
}
```